# Do we still need the node attachments folder?

Tags: attachment, corda

It seems the uploaded attachments are stored in table [ATTACHMENTS] as a blob. Now the node attachments folder is left empty.  What is the purpose of having such a folder?

Thanks.

\Sean

Answer (score 1):

No, that folder is a relic from a time when attachments were stored as files. It has been removed from Corda 1 onwards.